# A difficulty in understanding the solution of a problem.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question and its answer is given below:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

But I do not understand the following:

1-why all the critical points equal to $ c = \frac{2}{n^2 + n +2}$?

2-why to test this is the only critical point we compute second order derivative?

3-How is the sequence of determinants $\{ D_{i}\}_{i = 1}^{n}$ calculated?

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: I don't understand your problem in (3). Are you asking for the $(-1)^m m!(c^\cdots)^m$ factor?

Comment: yes I am asking about this @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla and the elements of the matrix also.

Comment: The components of the Hessian are the 2nd-order partial derivatives. For the factor, use a well-know property of determinants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

(1) Use that $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = A$:
$$A = (1 - x_1 - 2 x_2 - \cdots - n x_n) = (1 - A - 2 A - \cdots - n A) = \cdots$$

(2) Because we want know if is max/min?

(3) The second-order partial derivatives are already calculated...

Comment: for (2) why this is the way to say that we do not have critical points more than this?

Comment: In (1) it was already established that there is a single critical point (for positive $x_i$). Now it is just a matter of deciding if it is a minimum, maximum or saddle point.

Comment: @hopefully, see the comment by PierreCarre.

Comment: @PierreCarre, start your comment like me (with @...) and the user will be pinged.

Comment: Got it @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla !