# A difficulty in understanding the solution of a problem.2

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

The problem and its solution is given here :

[A difficulty in understanding the solution of a problem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157883/a-difficulty-in-understanding-the-solution-of-a-problem)

But I do not understand how $f_{x_{k}x_{k}}^{''} = -k(k + 1) c^{\frac{n^2 + n -2}{2}}$ and $f_{x_{k}x_{j}}^{''} = -k(j) c^{\frac{n^2 + n -2}{2}}$ , could anyone explains this for me please?

Comment: This is the value of these derivatives in point $(c,c,...,c)$

Comment: you mean I just try to calculate some of them and evaluate them at $(c,c,c,....)$ and I will see the patern? @JaroslawMatlak

Comment: Yes. And if there are still some problems, please share your effort with us.

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak okay thank you :)